# Relay connections

Tags: voltage, current, ac, relay, three-phase

I am planning to use this 4 pole relay - [Datasheet](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e/search_num/index.jsp?c=detail&part_no=AHER3191&large_g_cd=1&medium_g_cd=11&small_g_cd=112&series_cd=3881)

In the datasheet, I noticed the below image:

[image]

So, should the 12V be connected across pins 5 & 8 only right?

What is use of pins 6 & 7?

Additional question: If you can tell me whether this relay is NO or NC, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 12V should be connected across pins 5 and 8. Pins 6 and 7 form a Normally Closed contact (NC), and the other four are Normally Open (NO). Note that the NC contact is for small currents only, while the four NO contacts are suitable for larger currents.

Comment: @Justme, could you please help me with an answer?

Comment: @Freshman Why as me that under someone elses answer, is there something wrong that you don't accept in this answer? Also you asked most of these questions in your previous question about the same relay and got answers to those.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you identified pins 6 & 7 as Normally closed contact? And when the coil is given a voltage of 12V, how does the pins behave?